# Wordpress multiple query on one page error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two queries on one page. The first queries the current post and if it's a subcategory of a main category it displays those subcategory posts. The second queries the current category slug. There error is that the second query is showing the category from the first query. Is wp_reset_query not working? The weird thing is this only happens on a live server. My local it works fine.

```
   //First query
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
          if (cat_is_ancestor_of(26, $childcat)) {

              $subcat =  $childcat->cat_name;

    }}

    $sub_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'work',
     'category_name' => $subcat,
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'orderby'=> 'date',
      'order'=> 'DESC',
      'paged'=> $paged,
       'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() )


    ) );

    if ( $sub_query->have_posts() ): ?>

    <?php while ( $sub_query->have_posts() ) : $sub_query->the_post();  ?>
     // content
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 

    //second query
       if ( is_single() ) {
    $cats =  get_the_category();
    $cat = $cats[0];
  } else {
    $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
  }
  $cat_slug = $cat->slug;

    $work_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'work',
     'category_name' => $cat_slug,
      'posts_per_page' => 12,
      'orderby'=> 'date',
      'order'=> 'DESC',
      'paged'=> $paged,
     'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() )


    ) );

  if ( $work_query->have_posts() ): ?>

    <?php while ( $work_query->have_posts() ) : $work_query->the_post(); ?>
   // content
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
use this before wp_query

reffer this link
https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination